# Can a TreeSet be used in a similar manner to a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, prefix, treeset

This is for Java programming. I've been working on creating a function that effectively finds and remove if values from a list can act as prefixes for previous values in it, and I'm trying to code something with a good runtime.

After a lot of digging and asking around, I came upon someone suggesting to use a treeset as a binary search tree (BST)

Now, to be frank, I'm not too clear on BST as they're a new concept to me, so I would appreciate tips pushing me to the right direction.

Apparently, the treeset has some "VERY useful functions"

Comment: *Curious:* What is a BNS? A [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) is abbreviated BST.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TreeMap data structure. TreeMap is implemented as a red black tree, which is a self-balancing binary search tree.

Comment: I see, can you elaborate on how would i go about that?

Comment: FWIW - a [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is `A NavigableSet implementation based on a TreeMap`.  So you don't have to use a `TreeMap` _per se_; `TreeSet` works just the same.